# How would Water and wind current work on a fantasy earth?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, alternate-worlds

My world is flat. Water constantly pours over the edge, where it becomes vapor  and forms clouds.

Assuming that magic is involved to create Earth-like gravity, what effects would this setup have on the wind conditions, air currents and water currents of this world? Assume no magic is involved to change the way these things work otherwise. If it is impossible to have any wind or currents, what possible changes could I make to the setup without adding magic to create them? Finally, is it possible for the human race to exist on such a world, and develop into a complex modern society?

The crust of this world is the size of the Earth's, and the depth of the ocean is roughly the same here as it is in real life. Global temperature is also roughly the same.

Comment: [Water on a world that is flat](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/65390/water-on-a-world-that-is-flat) from five hours ago bears striking resemblance, in concept and also in question layout; perhaps this was a bit more inspired than intended. The answer to that also specifically addresses currents and wind.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit the question a bit? Some of it is hard to understand as written.

Comment: Yeah I checked it out on my phone while half-asleep and I'm not that good with a touchscreen anyway so go right ahead I'm not quite sure what information will be needed to answer this question as I'm not quite sure how having a flat Earth would impact the overall environment and ecosystem so if you need any more information please tell me. True my question does bear some resemblance to that but I'm more concerned with air currents that I am with the water.

Comment: @Zxyrra, the two questions are about different worlds in one key respect, this question has an open cycle where people can fall off the edge, the other is closed and walled.

Comment: @BryanMcClure, does the world spin and does it have a moon?

Comment: @Separatrix I would imagine that it doesn't Spin and the Moon and Sun travel around the Flat Earth

Comment: What are the limits of your world? What is beyond the edge? Can the water go there? What are the limits of the sky? Where can the clouds drift off to? What do you mean global temperature is about the same? Are there poles? Does it rotate? These are legitimate questions.

Comment: Water turn into clouds after they go over the edge.

Comment: Use the Discworld solution, "Arrangements are made..."

Comment: @John ??????????????????????????

Comment: Terry Pratchett's discworld is a flat pizza shaped planet on the back of four giant elephants on the back of one giant sea turtle who swims through space.

Answer (score 2):

It would work better if it was a bubble earth, a flat earth surrounded by a cosmic bubble that kept the air and water contained. Below the flat earth was a reservoir of water, that the water in the sides of the world fell into, and throughout the flat world were "springs" that magically drew water from the reservoir into the surface world.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're going to have obvious water currents leading edgeward; but if the resulting clouds you mention don't get displaced upwards somehow, you're going to run out of water (and air) except where the landscape cuts off passage to the edge. Same as when you dump a bucket of water on a flat surface - it keeps spreading out until it goes over an edge or can be held together via surface tension.

Vapor doesn't rise against gravity, after all - it's pushed out of the way by colder (denser) air, and sits on top of that.

So, you're going to need some additional factor to get your clouds back up over the edge.

Comment: Not to mention to keep your air from pouring out over the sides just like the water.

Comment: It would work better if it was a bubble earth, a flat earth surrounded by a cosmic bubble that kept the air and water contained.  Below the flat earth was a reservoir of water, that the water in the sides of the world fell into, and throughout the flat world were "springs" that magically drew water from the reservoir into the surface world.

Comment: You also have consider what to do about the planet constantly shrinking from the erosion caused by water flowing over the edge. Niagara falls moves about 3ft a year.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus  The dome is a good solution, you should turn that into an answer, it keeps the air and water contained. it also creates a massive strange ocean under the world, that gets barely any sunlight. Its also not too far off from how several ancient cultures thought the world worked.